# Height measuring system thru Webcam

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

Hi sirs I'm trying to develop a program that will measure a person's height via WEBCAM

but I still don't have any idea on how am I going to do that all I got so far is accessing the webcam @_@

Can anyone teach me more on EMGU developing please :) thanks in advance

this is all I have T_T I hope anyone will be kind enough to teach me

```
void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
    imageBox1.Image = ImageFrame;
}

private void Fitting_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        capture = new Capture();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
    {
        textBox1.Text = excpt.Message;
        return;
    }
    Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
    captureInProgress = true;
    btnRecord.Text = "Pause";
}

private void Fitting_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (capture != null)
    {
        capture.Dispose();
    }
}

private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (captureInProgress == true)
    {
        Application.Idle -= ProcessFrame;
        captureInProgress = false;
        btnRecord.Text = "Record";
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
        captureInProgress = true;
        btnRecord.Text = "Stop";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything so far other than webcam part.

I will give you a start.

Face detection using C# Example
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462527/Camera-Face-Detection-in-Csharp-Using-Emgu-CV-Open
Try to see if this can be extended to detect the hair. If you can detect hair,

Detect object from image based on object color by C#
http://kishordgupta.wordpress.com/2010/12/24/detect-object-from-image-based-on-object-color-by-c/

Comment: thanks for the tip sir...


sir would it be possible to get the height,width of a person using canny edges?